# why is the javascript and css unaltered on the web browser?

Tags: browser, web, web-applications

I just ran into a problem, While I was updating the js and css files for my website on a server, I do not see the immediate change. However, if I were to edit these files on a local computer or go on *incognito mode* on chrome, I see the change right away.
let's say I have:

```
div{width:100px}
```

after I change it to `div{width:200px}`, when I pop open the *developer tool*, it still reads `div{width:100px}`.

I feel like I need to clear something for the broswer,  any explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the caching headers you are using for static resources. The browser is likely using a cached version.